# Codeigniter on AWS Cache and Error log/display or debug not showing

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-ec2, error-handling

I am using CI(Codeigniter) with AWS server, but CI is not showing PHP error instead of PHP error it shows me This page isn’t working, I have tried everything setting

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(-1);
    define('MP_DB_DEBUG', true);
```

into my index.php file but still not showing error, however when I create test file into my server, not in the directory of Codeigniter on that file it shows me the error,

another issue is my cache on the server if I change my file it takes time to reflect the change multiple times to I have saved the file I didn't configure SVN now because of some reasons. but sure I will do later, I need the solution for my current situation. Any help will be appreciatable

Comment: check if ENVIRONMENT variable is development mode or in production. If its in production then change it development. it will be in idex,php file

Comment: indeed, that is how you are supposed to change error reporting in CI (with the ENV variable) as for the second part of your question: please keep questions to 1 per ;)

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy i did change it but no luck !! i don't know what wrong with it. is there is anywhere else i have to change it?

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

In you configuration file in codeigniter or core php file.

Hope this works for you.